# Form with default value when loading django page

Tags: python, django

I would like that when the page is loaded, a value or the default filter of the form is already triggered.

In this case, I have a boolean filter that returns True or False and I wanted the True to be loaded by default because it filters items in HTMl

```html
Executado = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='exact').initial={'Executado':TRUE}
```

Comment: Could you share your view and template?